# Where to include acknowledgements for used graphics

Tags: citations, etiquette, graphics, acknowledgement

In the current technical report that I write, I have used graphic from an online-source where their policy requires that the author of the drawing has to be acknowledged in case that the drawing is to be used.

This policy applies to electronic and printed formats of the given work.

Where do I place the acknowledgement for this drawings? Probably the proper way would be to use footnote in the page where the drawing is shown but, the policy requires that the name of the author is written. I would like to avoid such content in the footnotes where I discuss important information.

Is it OK if I do the acknowledgement in an appendix in the end of the report?

Comment: You should include the authorship as part of a citation in the graphic (figure) label. There are some examples from Pierce College Library [here](https://library.peirce.edu/html/citations/figures). You are labeling your figures, right?

Comment: if by label you mean adding a caption to them, then yes. if I misunderstood, can you please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did on my papers is under the image (often needed to use an image editor) is put in a caption such as "Title of image (if applicable), author of image, year created" Similar to @mkennedy's comment but I prefer adding the citation into the image. I DO NOT alter the original I add extra pixels to the bottom of the image size.

Then in my works cited I would say "Title of image, author name, year, Retrieved from..."

Answer (score 3):

You want the reference close to the actual picture. You could go with @Memj's suggestion in the other comment. Or simply put it in the caption:

```
Fig. 19: Measured relationship between galaxy distance and
red shift. (Figure reproduced with permission from http://abc.org,
copyright Adam Smith, 2015.)
```